# Change sitecore item without redirect

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore7.2, sitecore-mvc

I have a custom pipeline processor inserted  after ItemResolver in which I overwrite the current context item with a new item selected by the content editor from a droplink.

If I go to that dynamic item via a normal request through my website and through my processor and i change my context item, it will stil render the same item:

```
public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
{
  // some code
  Context.Item = dropLink.TargetItem;
}
```

Strangely, if I issue a request via the item API, sitecore changes the item successfully

```
//api call
Context.Item = Context.Database.SelectSingleItem("fast:/sitecore/content/mysite/dynamicitem");
```

Here is my config file:

```
<pipelines>
 <httpRequestBegin>
   <processor  patch:after="* @type='Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ItemResolver, Sitecore.Kernel']"  type="MyDll.Web.Pipelines.LandingPageResolver,MyDll.Web" />
 </httpRequestBegin>
</pipelines>
```

Comment: can you try to patch before itemresolver not after it?

Comment: So you are saying that, in the same processor, you make some api call and then the item does get affected? You also do a SelectSingleItem instead of dropLink.TargetItem, could you test the SelectSingleItem without the api call?

Comment: I don't make an API call in the processor, I issue an API call for an item (from the browser for example) and in the processor I change the context item with a random one, I can successfully change the context item. I also tested with SelectSingleItem, without success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using MVC the item is resolved (again) using a different set of pipelines, so you need to patch into there instead.

The `GetFromRouteUrl` processor in the `mvc.getPageItem` pipeline sets `args.Result` to the item matching the requested URL which is then eventually set to `Context.Item`, so it essentially resets the item back to the "correct" item based on the URL and that overwrites the changes you made earlier.

You need to add a need processor to the `mvc.getPageItem` with some logic to check if the context item has already been resolved.

Update your code in the ItemResolver and store a boolean to indicate that you have already resolved using custom logic, this saves having to run the resolving logic twice:

```cs
public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
{
  // some code
  Context.Item = dropLink.TargetItem;
  Context.Items["custom::ItemResolved"] = true;
}
```

Create a new Class that checks if your custom logic has already resolved the item:

```cs
public class CheckItemResolved: GetPageItemProcessor
{
  public override void Process(GetPageItemArgs args)
  {
    if (args.Result == null)
    {
        var resolved = Sitecore.Context.Items["custom::ItemResolved"];
        if (MainUtil.GetBool(resolved, false))
        {
            // item has previously been resolved
            args.Result = Sitecore.Context.Item;
        }
    }

    return;
  }
}
```

And then patch this in:

```xml
<pipelines>
  <mvc.getPageItem>
    <processor type="MyProject.Custom.Pipelines.CheckItemResolved, MyProject.Custom"
        patch:before="*[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.GetPageItem.GetFromRouteUrl, Sitecore.Mvc']" />
  </mvc.getPageItem>
</pipelines>
```

The pipeline immediately after is `GetFromFromUrl()` which would normally set `args.Result` by re-resolving the Item. By setting it back to Context.Item that processor will break out early and leave your previous logic alone.

You can find more details about [MVC and Pipelines in the documentation](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/mvc/mvc_and_pipelines).

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I used the trick with that bool flag and now I'm checking for that flag inside my CheckItemResolved class. If I find a resolved item, I just do args.Result = Context.Item;. I'm not sure why in your code snippet you do this check if(args.Result != null). For me, that Result is always null, not sure if your snippet just for me to understand or it's production code. Thanks again!

Comment: Great, glad it worked. We do the check since it is relevant for our code, it may be different for you so adjust as necessary. Setting `args.Result = Context.Item;` is perfectly valid, but the next processor (`GetFromOldContext`) does exactly the same thing, hence I set it to null, but it's just preference.