# Error resolving URL's that do not have a space

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore8.2

Currently in an effort to upgrade our site from 7.2 to 8.2 161115 and getting a Document Not Found error if a URL does **not** have a space in it.

Almost all of the URL's in our site have a space in the content item name and work fine. Only a few don't.

For example these work:

```
/Page Name/
/Page-Name/
/Page/Sub Page/
/Page/Sub-Page/
```

These do not work:

```
/Page
/Page/SecondaryPage
```

This error occurs on a special template we have called "Context Resolver" which forwards a visitor to a different page based on rules. The template has three fields:

```
Forwarding Enabled (checkbox)
Rules (ruleset)
Default Item (droptree)
```

The idea is that these items make decisions on where to send a visitor.  We have a pipeline that runs the following code:

```
public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
{
    if (args == null) return;

    var item = Sitecore.Context.Item;
    if (item == null) return;

    if (item.TemplateID != SitecoreDefinitions.ContextForwarderTemplate) return;

    if (!item.IsContextForwarderEnabled()) return;

    var rulesItem = item.Fields["Rules"];
    if (rulesItem != null)
    {
        RuleFactory.InvalidateCache();
        var rules = RuleFactory.GetRules<RuleContext>(rulesItem);
        if (sitecoreRepository.ExecuteRules(rules.Rules))
            return;                   
    }

    ReferenceField refItem = item.Fields["Context"];
    Context.Item = refItem.TargetItem;
}
```

This work's great, as expected from our previous 7.2 site on any URL with a space.  If there is no space, it fails.  Without the rules, there is no difference, so the error is happening from this line:

```
Sitecore.Context.Item = someNewItem
```

Thoughts?  We can easily reproduce this issue with this template type on the working URL's by removing the space, and add a space on failing URL's to make them work.

Comment: I don't see the line you mention the error being on (`Sitecore.Context.Item = someNewItem`) in the `Process` function that you posted there.

Comment: The last line:  `Context.Item = refItem.TargetItem;`   I can step through the pipeline and the correct context item is assigned every time.  It's throwing the not found after it exits my pipeline and a space is not in the URL path

Comment: The issue is most likely that the Context.Item is resolved again by the MVC specific pipelines. Try the solution here to tap into the MVC pipelines so it respects your custom logic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40358809/661447

Comment: This was the solution